# Video suddenly unaccelerated, wrong resolution

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, lubuntu, radeon

Lubuntu 14.04 fully up to date. It was working fine until I turned on my laptop today and the screen was 1024x768 instead of the native 1280x800, unaccelerated. `lxrandr` shows 1024x768 as the only available resolution. lspci output:

`01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]`

`lsmod` shows that the `radeon` module is loaded.

Any ideas? (Yes I did turn it off and on again!)

Comment: Same problem as http://askubuntu.com/questions/492172/kubuntu-14-04lts-radeon-rs690-x1270-unable-to-use-resolution-of-more-than-10 , same solution.

Answer (score 0):

This article might be helpful:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Has you check the available screen resolutions with xrandr command yet? If the undetected screen resolution was available from other output of your graphic card, you could add it to the output used easily according to that wiki.

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved it with http://askubuntu.com/questions/492172/kubuntu-14-04lts-radeon-rs690-x1270-unable-to-use-resolution-of-more-than-10 . For some reason askubuntu doesn't let me enter that as an answer and immediately converts it to a comment.